# Why does [age-of-sigmar] say to always add [warhammer-40k]?

Tags: discussion, tags

In the tag excerpt (added by TheLethalCarrot):

> Always use in conjunction with the [warhammer-40k](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warhammer-40k) tag.

Age of Sigmar is a sequel (but completely different cosmology) to Warhammer Fantasy. [It is no more related to 40k than Fantasy is.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/34166/13024)

Unless a question is specifically asking about both properties, it should never have both tags.

I thought I'd better check why that was added before I removed it.

Comment: Does tagging @TheLethalCarrot work?

Comment: does not, but don't worry I'm never far away.

Comment: I hope the [warhammer-fantasy] tag is more appropriate (although that excerpt _also_ says "Always use in conjunction with the [warhammer-40k] tag")

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Our tag usage guidance and information in tag wiki excerpts (and tag wikis if we have them) generally sucks, to be frank. Over the past few years I've slowly been going back through old tags and fixing a few things up and standardising a format in some places. I've also tried to make sure all new tags at least have a tag wiki excerpt (though I haven't had time in a while to keep these up to date).

As part of this process I guess I came across [age-of-sigmar](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-sigmar) at some point. I'm not a Warhammer expert and I really don't know that much about it. I must have naively assumed that W40K was the main work with the others being spin offs so keeping [warhammer-40k](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warhammer-40k) as the main franchise tag (as well as for the specific work) made sense to me at the time.

As it turns out my information was wrong here. You can safely edit the tag wiki excerpt to be more correct as you see fit here!

Comment: As a follow-up, there is a [tag:warhammer] that is currently unused. That would be best as a synonym for [tag:warhammer-fantasy] or just let it die. There will be a `[tag:warhammer-old-world]` coming "soon" as a rename/relaunch of `[tag:warhammer-fantasy]`

Comment: Tag edits made and awaiting review.